# How can I use a loop to create new x1 and x2 values every 2.8 units?

Tags: python

I am trying to move my x1 and x2 values 2.8 units to the right, but still keep the first values the same. I am assuming I can use some sort of loop, but I am not sure how I would go about it.

For example, x1=3.5 and x2=3.9, I want my program to iterate the next x1 and x2 values over and over again, so that the next x1=6.3 and x2=6.7, and so on.

```
x1 = sheet2.cell_value(row,25)
x2 = sheet2.cell_value(row,26)
x1 += 2.8
x2 += 2.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you want to add 2.8 to x1,x2 for 10 times,

so you need a do a loop operation which add 2.8 to previous value of x.
and update it

how can you achive this

using for loop

```
x1=3.5
x2=3.9
times = 10 
for i in range(times):
    print(round(x1,2),round(x2,2))
    x1+=2.8
    x2+=2.8
```

using while loop

```
x1=3.5
x2=3.9
count = 10 
while count>0:
        print(round(x1,2),round(x2,2))
        x1+=2.8
        x2+=2.8
        count-=1
```

using formula

```
x1=3.5
x2=3.9
count = 10
for i in range(count):
    x1 = x1 +2.8*i
    x2 = x2 + 2.8*i
    print(round(x1,2),round(x2,2))
```